# How to get user online status throught browser (URL needed)

Tags: api, roblox, status

I used the below link.

`https://api.roblox.com/users/**$UserID**/onlinestatus`

for example:

https://api.roblox.com/users/543226965/onlinestatus

I have been receiving an error message from last time. The error message is given below.

`{"errors":[{"code":404,"message":"NotFound"}]}`

I heard the roblox API have been changed, but I can not find the right solutions, so I will be grateful for any answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to access the user's online status. As of right now, you can access this information by querying `https://api.roblox.com/users/<user_id>`, which returns a JSON object. Looking up `IsOnline` in the dictionary should return what you're trying to get

Here's an example I coded in Python:

```py
import requests
res = requests.get(url='https://api.roblox.com/users/543226965')
res = res.json()
print(res['IsOnline'])

>>> True/False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The old version of the online status gave me more information like when user was playing/coding etc. Is it possible to get more than true/false in isOnline funcrion like mentioned in previous sentence?

Comment: I am not sure whether there is a way that you can do that, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

its very hard to find solutions for these problems on stack overflow I tried before but lucky I am a python coder very experienced in the api, here is what you are looking for ^.^

```
import requests
end = []
#usernames = open('usernames.txt','r',errors='ignore').read().splitlines()

usernames = ['roblox']
username = usernames.pop(0)
u = str(username) 
r = requests.get(f'https://www.roblox.com/user.aspx?username={username}').url
if 'www.roblox.com/users/' in r:
        userid = r.split('/')[-2]
        id = [userid]
        b = requests.post('https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/last-online', json={'userIds': id}).json()['lastOnlineTimestamps'][0]['lastOnline'].split('T')[0]
        print(f'{b}:{u}')
```

Comment: One more: is it also possible to get more information like userPresencyType, lastLocation, gameId? If yes please show how it is possible please show me how to do this using cUrl.

Comment: It possible to exchange python to cUrl as following:  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/last-online" --data  '{ "userIds": [myUserIdNumber] }' where my UserID Number should be replaced by a user number for example 123456789.

Comment: There isnt one url to do it all but if u want the user id you should do print(f'{userid}:{b}:{u}')